# Javascript validation for the zip code field

Tags: javascript, validation

I've the JavaScript code to validate a Zip code field in my page and that is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var zip=$("#zip").val();
if (zip == '') {
               errorMessage = REG_FIELD_EMPTY_ZIP;
               $('#msg_zip').html(errorMessage).show();
               }
               else {
                if ((zip.length) < 5) 
                    {
                    errorMessage = REG_FIELD_LENGTH_ZIP;
                $('#msg_zip').html(errorMessage).show();
                }
                    else 
                    {
                if (!reg.test(zip)) {
                errorMessage = REG_FIELD_ONLYDIGITS_ZIP;
                $('#msg_zip').html(errorMessage).show();
                }
               else {
                $('#msg_zip').html('').hide();
                    }
             }
           }
           </script>
```

Here, i want to add some more conditions as: 
1> this zip code field should also support Canadian Zip-code format (A#A #A#) with or without space it should accept. If the value is not in the Canadian Zip-code format, 
2> It should accept only 5 digits.
How can i modify the above script so that i can make my zip code field to accept canadian zip-code format as well. 
By searching i've found some regular-expression to accept canadian zip-code as /^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$/; But when i tested it, it is not accepting the small case letters.
Can anyone clarify how to change my script so that it should accept the canadian-zip code or to accept only 5 digits.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have for canadian zip-code is correct. If you want it to accept small case letters, you have to use it with case-insensitive option(**i**):

```
(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$/i).test(zip)
```

Regex for 5 digits:

```
/^\d{5}$/
```

Combining these two:

```
(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$/i).test(zip) || (/^\d{5}$/).test(zip)
```

Comment: /^\d{5}$/ accepts exactly 5 digits. Or You mean you want it to accept more than 5?